# Postgres domain type information available in JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

When querying columns that are a Postgres domain type using JDBC (with driver https://jdbc.postgresql.org/ version 42.3.3), there doesn't seem to be any way of getting the domain information; only the underlying datatype is reported.

```
create domain account_uuid_type as uuid;
create domain customer_uuid_type as uuid;

create table test (
    account_uuid account_uuid_type,
    customer_uuid customer_uuid_type
);

insert into test
(account_uuid, customer_uuid)
values
(
    '4c1210c2-e785-4462-926c-1789cd1aa88c',
    'b155e10c-10cd-4a11-b427-d7c78397b617'
);
```

When querying the table from Java using `select account_uuid, customer_uuid from test`, the information from the `PgResultSet` is that the `pgType` values for the columns is `uuid`. There's no mention of the more specific domain information. Is there a way of asking Postgres to add the domain information into the metadata?

Comment: What more information do you want? You can use the query `select * from information_schema.domains;`

Comment: Fair point. I was hoping to get the `customer_uuid_type` and `account_uuid_type` as metadata items as part of the main query, so that I can use it to define custom behaviour when mapping to a data object using https://jdbi.org/ . I agree that I could, instead, use a mechanism that finds out all the column types in advance and uses that information to perform the customisation. It's not as clean as doing it inline with the domain type information, though.